# Cannot populate form controls from controller

Tags: javafx

Firstly, my Maven file, as I'm not sure if I am using the newest version of JavaFX or not:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

My *main* method (just a proof of concept:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Clinica c = new Clinica();
        c.setNombre("Nombre");
        c.setCodigoPostal("CP");
        c.setPoblacion("Malaga");
        c.setDireccion("Calle Se");
        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            SampleController sc=new SampleController();
            sc.setClinic(c);
            loader.setController(sc);
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My controller:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField zip;
    @FXML
    private TextField town;
    @FXML
    private TextField address;



    private Clinica c;

    public SampleController() {
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        this.name = new TextField(this.c.getNombre());
        this.zip = new TextField(this.c.getCodigoPostal());
        this.town = new TextField(this.c.getPoblacion());
        this.address = new TextField(this.c.getDireccion());
    }

    public void setClinic(Clinica c) {
        this.c = c;

    }

}
```

And my FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Do not edit this file it is generated by e(fx)clipse from ../src/main/resources/es/ortoplus/migration/Sample.fxgraph
-->

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" vgap="5" hgap="5" alignment="CENTER">

    <children>
        <TextField id="name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/> 
        <TextField id="zip" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/> 
        <TextField id="town" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/> 
        <TextField id="address" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/> 
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

**The problem**: I cannot populate the form.

I've tried **not creating instances in the initialize method**, expecting that the binding and injection were *automatically* done, but all controls were null when the initialize method is executed (so I had a NPE).

Then, as the code shows, I initialized the fields manually and set the values, but the form is shown empty and it seems there is no binding between view and the controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace `id` by `fx:id` in your FXML file and do not instantiate `TextField` again in your `ìnitialize` method.

Comment: @Pagbo Thank you! I've been blocked by the whole day for that silly mistake

Comment: You're welcome. Just to be more accurate (if s.o read this), `id` is used for CSS (styling component) and `fx:id` for injection. Beside note, you can remove `initialize` arguments and the interface implementation and add the `@FXML` annotation instead : something like `@FXML
    private void initialize(){ ... }`. This is cleaner.